# AppDelegate feature in UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a viewcontroller that has code to implement the Facebook window. the problem is that to run the code, I need this url:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
 openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
 self.openedURL = url;
// attempt to extract a token from the url
 return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];       
 }
```

...and as I have understood it can only be run in the app delegate, but I need it to get the url. If I simply add it to the delegate it is not called, and I don't know when it is called and how. any suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried using NSNotifications?

Comment: I mean, there is this: NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification =
@"com.facebook.samples.SendRequestsHowTo:FBSessionStateChangedNotification";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a property of the app delegate in another class you can use the following code (assuming the the name of your app delegate class is AppDelegate) in your view controller class:

```
NSURL *theURL = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication shardApplication]delegate] openedURL];
```

I'm assuming here, that you want to pass this URL along to your controller. You also need to import the AppDelegate.h file into your controller.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this code. When you log theURL in your viewController, what does it give you? And what did you do to get this error?

Comment: when I launch the app, is this code called automatically? I have the facebook app code in the URL schemes

Comment: @Alessandro, I don't know -- it depends where you put it. I would put it in the viewDidLoad: method of whatever view controller you want it in. You should also log self.openedURL in your app delegate to make sure it's not null there.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see the url you can use a global variable to store it from this function and use it later, let us assume you have a singleton called appData declare a static variable

.h file

```
+(appData*)sharedAppData;
@property (nonatomic,retain) nsurl * myUrl;
```

in the .m file

```
static appData* = nil;

 initFunction {

      if(! appData) {  appData = [[appData alloc] init];}
  }

 +(appData*)sharedAppData{
  return appData;
  }
```

in the init function initialize this object  so in any where in the system you can access your this data by

appData * data  = [appData sharedData];
data.myurl =....
nslog(@"my url %@",data.url);